# How to repeat item in listview

Tags: android, excel, listview, arraylist, hashmap

I have the listview from the exel:

```
try {

       Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(getAssets().open("bos.xls"));
       Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
       for(int i = 0; i < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
       Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
              Cell form1 = row.getCell(0);
              Cell form2 = row.getCell(1);
              Cell form3 = row.getCell(2);

              IrrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

              HashMap<String, Object> hm;

            hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hm.put(Form1, form1.getStringCellValue());
            hm.put(Form2, form2.getStringCellValue());
            hm.put(Form3, form3.getStringCellValue());
            IrrList.add(hm);

              SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, IrrList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { Form1,  Form2, Form3 },
                                   new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3 });   
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
         }

         } catch(Exception ex) {
             return;
         }
```

When I use it I have the one value in my listview.
How can i correct it?

I tried to add this before "HashMap hm;":

```
  for(int i1 = 0, l = IrrList.size(); i1 < l; i1++){
"I dont know what write here"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Initilize the `ArrayList` **before the for loop** and set the `listview adapter` **after the for loop**

```
IrrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
for(int i = 0; i < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
   Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
          Cell form1 = row.getCell(0);
          Cell form2 = row.getCell(1);
          Cell form3 = row.getCell(2);              

          HashMap<String, Object> hm;

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(Form1, form1.getStringCellValue());
        hm.put(Form2, form2.getStringCellValue());
        hm.put(Form3, form3.getStringCellValue());
        IrrList.add(hm);             
     }
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, IrrList,
        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { Form1,  Form2, Form3 },
                               new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3 });   
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! =) I knew it is simple )